# How to interrupt a blocking `os.Open` call waiting on a Fifo in Go?

Tags: go

I'm writing a Jupyter kernel for Go, and before executing the Go code I create a side named pipe (`syscall.Mkfifo`) as a mechanism to allow one to publish html, images, etc.

My kernel creates the fifo, and then opens it for reading in a new goroutine and polls for input accordingly. Now, **opening a fifo for reading is a blocking operation** (it waits until someone opens on the other side).

But some programs are not interested in using this mechanism and will never open the other side of the fifo. When this happens my goroutine leaks, and it forever waits on the opening fifo -- even after I remove it.

The code looks more or less (less error handling) like this:

```golang
    ...
    syscall.Mkfifo(pipePath, 0600)
    go func() {
      pipeReader, _ := os.Open(pipePath)
      go poll(pipeReader) // Reads and process each entry until pipeReader is closed.
      <-doneChan
      pipeReader.Close()
    }
    go func() {
      <-doneChan
      os.Remove(pipePath)
    }
```

Where `doneChan` is closed when the program I start finishes executing.

And the issue is that `os.Open(pipePath)` never returns if the other end is never opened,
even though the `os.Remove(pipePath)` is properly executed.

Is there a way to forcefully interrupt `os.Open(pipePath)`, or another way to achieving the same thing ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, it took just a bit more coffee and thinking.

I forgot that I can open the other end of the pipe myself, if I know the program I executed didn't open it. And this unblocks the open for reading.

The revised code, in case anyone bumps into this:

```golang
    pipeOpenedForReading := false
    var muFifo sync.Mutex{}
    syscall.Mkfifo(pipePath, 0600)
    go func() {
      pipeReader, _ := os.Open(pipePath)
      muFifo.Lock()
      pipeOpenedForReading = true
      muFifo.Unlock()
      go poll(pipeReader) // Reads and process each entry until pipeReader is closed.
      <-doneChan
      pipeReader.Close()
    }
    go func() {
      <-doneChan
      muFifo.Lock()
      if !pipeOpenedForReading {
        // Open for writing, unblocking the os.Open for reading.
        f, err = os.OpenFile(pipePath, O_WRONLY, 0600)
        if err == nil {
          close(f)
        }
      }
      muFifo.Unlock
      os.Remove(pipePath)
    }
```

Comment: I think you're overengineering your solution: once you have an `*os.File`, you can set read and/or write deadlines on it so that the relevant operations time out "naturally", and no, you don't need locking. Something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/zB5XZqSYwHo) should have you covered.

Comment: Also, except in very constrained systems, "leaking" a single goroutine to handle input is usually not a concern, it just sits idle for the duration of the process. This is common when you can't force the fd to close, like stdin for example.

Comment: @kostix: I think your suggestion doesn't work, because you don't have an `*os.File`: remember it  blocks on `os.Open` so you haven't got the `*os.File` yet. There is no way to close or set any deadline.
Thanks for the try though :)

Comment: @JimB Agreed ... but since I'm implementing a Jupyter kernel, these executions will happen often, and I don't want to leak one goroutine every time. Also out of principle and curiosity ... there ought to be a way to do this correctly without leaks.

This solution is not "pretty", but so far it seems to have worked.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can open FIFO in non-blocking way, according to [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html). So something like this should work:

```
    go func() {
      pipeReader, _ := os.OpenFile(pipePath, syscall.O_RDONLY|syscall.O_NONBLOCK, 0)
      go poll(pipeReader) // Reads and process each entry until pipeReader is closed.
      <-doneChan
      pipeReader.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that could work also!

Curiously `os.OpenFile` didn't document this option (nor does it define `O_NONBLOCK`). Reading the docs more careful on [fifo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) they do mention that non-blocking open for reading will return successfully immediately (I was surprised, I expected it to fail immediately), so we get an `*os.File`. But according to this [blog post](https://medium.com/@cpuguy83/non-blocking-i-o-in-go-bc4651e3ac8d) reading from this file will return EAGAIN instead of blocking. I have to try it...